# Incorrect lookup as user, but correct at root

Tags: macos, networking, rubygems

I have a new OSX machine running Mavericks and have an interesting situation getting to rubygems.org.

As a normal user:

```
  $ curl http://rubygems.org|head                
  curl: (7) Failed connect to rubygems.org|head:8080; Connection refused
```

But using sudo:

```
   $ sudo curl http://rubygems.org |head 
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                           Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100  9181    0  9181    0     0   6847      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  6851
  <!DOCTYPE html>    
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <meta name="google-site-verification" content="AuesbWQ9MCDMmC1lbDlw25RJzyqWOcDYpuaCjgPxEZY" />
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/touch-icon-iphone.png" />
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/touch-icon-ipad.png" />
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
   <link rel="fluid-icon" href="/fluid-icon.png"/>
   <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="RubyGems.org" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

I've never seen this before -- why does it go to 8080 as a user? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a proxy server configured in the user's environment? I'd start by running "set|grep 8080" to see if any variable contains 8080. It also seems like the pipe character wasn't recognized by bash, since curl seems to see |head as part of the hostname. Is this repeatable? Does it happen even with a space around the pipe (no, that should not be necessary, but if it changes the error, it might be illuminating). Was the original command copied from something such that the pipe might actually be some other non-ascii character?

Comment: The "|head" was there to show that I was using the same command got got different results. That said, your comment about "proxy" reminded me that I copied my shell config from another system and, sure enough, I had a proxy set there. So I'm marking this as correct.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've struggled far too long with copy-pasted commands that have a fancy long dash where I see a hyphen. I guess some blog framework likes the non-ascii dashes. Grrr... glad you found the proxy config!